# Accessing the phonebook on Galaxy S crashes the app

Tags: android, android-intent, contacts

Does anyone know how to access the contacts from the Galaxy S?

I have this line of code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
startActivity(intent);
```

and it works on the emulator as well as on the Samsung i5700.  I tried running my app on Samsung i9000 (Galaxy S) but it crashes.

I am getting the following error from LogCat:

```
08-23 11:28:19.511: INFO/ActivityManager(2234): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://com.android.contacts/contacts }
08-23 11:28:19.516: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(5067): Shutting down VM
08-23 11:28:19.516: WARN/dalvikvm(5067): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001dc20)
08-23 11:28:19.516: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5067): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
08-23 11:28:19.526: INFO/Lights(2234): set_light_backlight[0~255]:(42) gamma_value:(4) BRIGHTNESS_MODE(1)
08-23 11:28:19.526: VERBOSE/AudioHardwareALSA(2183): ------------------------>>>>>> ALSA OPEN mode 0,device 2 
08-23 11:28:19.526: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5067): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://com.android.contacts/contacts }
08-23 11:28:19.526: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5067):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1408)
08-23 11:28:19.526: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5067):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1378)
08-23 11:28:19.526: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5067):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2758)
08-23 11:28:19.526: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5067):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2864)
08-23 11:28:19.526: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5067):     at au.com.orionmedia.vidcall.KeypadActivity.onClick(KeypadActivity.java:313)
08-23 11:28:19.526: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5067):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2417)
08-23 11:28:19.526: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5067):     at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4232)
08-23 11:28:19.526: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5067):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3762)
08-23 11:28:19.526: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5067):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
08-23 11:28:19.526: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5067):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
08-23 11:28:19.526: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5067):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
08-23 11:28:19.526: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5067):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
08-23 11:28:19.526: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5067):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
08-23 11:28:19.526: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5067):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1713)
08-23 11:28:19.526: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5067):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1131)
08-23 11:28:19.526: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5067):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2070)
08-23 11:28:19.526: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5067):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1697)
08-23 11:28:19.526: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5067):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1691)
08-23 11:28:19.526: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5067):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-23 11:28:19.526: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5067):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-23 11:28:19.526: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5067):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
08-23 11:28:19.526: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5067):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-23 11:28:19.526: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5067):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-23 11:28:19.526: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5067):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:862)
08-23 11:28:19.526: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5067):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
08-23 11:28:19.526: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5067):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I tried accessing the phonebook from the launcher, and this is what I get:

```
08-23 17:50:53.885: INFO/ActivityManager(2244): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.android.contacts/com.sec.android.app.contacts.PhoneBookTopMenuActivity }
08-23 17:50:54.055: INFO/ContactsListActivity(2401): Called with action: com.android.contacts.action.LIST_DEFAULT
08-23 17:50:54.205: INFO/ActivityManager(2244): Displayed activity com.android.contacts/com.sec.android.app.contacts.PhoneBookTopMenuActivity: 208 ms (total 1265628 ms)
```

Based on those logs, I am guessing that the phone does not use the default contacts application and it does not handle the intent I am firing from my app.

I tried changing the URI I am passing to the intent, but it doesn't work either.

Has anybody else seen this problem? Any suggestions on what I can try next?

Thank you!
- Zarah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [`ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTACTS_URI`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html#CONTENT_URI) instead. You are using the Android 1.x API, and it is possible Samsung failed to test that sufficiently. My understanding is that the Samsung Galaxy S is an Android 2.x device.

Comment: Hi @CommonsWare! I failed to mention that I also tried using that, but I still get the same exception as above.  You are right though, Samsung Galaxy S is Android 2.1.  What confuses me in this case is that my other test phone, Samsung Galaxy Spica is also Android 2.1 and my intent works on there.

I am really at a loss here and I don't know what to do anymore.

Comment: @Zarah: it turns out this was already reported, and I have filed a bug to get the CTS fixed for Samsung's compatibility issue: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=10143  You can use `PackageManager` and `queryIntentActivities()` to test whether or not your `Intent` will match anything, then disable the menu choice or button or whatever triggers the code path where you try to start the activity.

Comment: Thanks! I implemented what you suggested and just set the button to View.GONE to prevent confusion. :) Hope this gets fixed soon!

Comment: @Zarah: You and me both. It's these sorts of bugs that fuel the fragmentation fears.

Answer (score 0):

we did a small fix but hoping that samsung will have it updated (we did catched that for the exception part soon)

use ComponentName

Answer (score 0):

Try this... It worked for me. (GALAXY S)

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName("com.android.contacts", "com.sec.android.app.contacts.PhoneBookTopMenuActivity");
intent.setComponent(componentName);
```

Then start your activity...

Comment: Hi @technofunc, does that mean you check first if the phone model is Galaxy S? Or will setting the intent that way work for other phone models as well? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Zarah. You have to check the model of the phone. This is explicitly for the Samsung Galaxy S (or other phones that use the same version). Hope this helps...

Comment: Try something like this: if (Build.DEVICE.equals("GT-I9000")){...}